# How To Search Date Range ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do I search date range using the controller? So far I am not able to solve it with the code that I used below. The search for Trip name & country is working.
(P.s I am new to this programming language...) Thank you in advance.

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string search, DateTime? startdate, DateTime?  enddate)
    {
        if (Session["StaffName"] != null)
        {
            //original
            DateTime str = DateTime.UtcNow;
            ViewBag.Datetime = str;
            ViewBag.startdate = startdate;
            ViewBag.enddate = enddate;
            var Trips = from x in db.Trips
                        select x;
            if (search != null)
            {
                return View(Trips.Where(x => x.TripName.Contains(search) || x.Country.Contains(search)  || search == null).ToList());
            }
            if (startdate != null && enddate != null)
            {
                return View(Trips.Where(x =>  startdate > x.startDate && x.endDate < enddate ).ToList());
            }
            return View(Trips.ToList());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What problem are you having? And if `search` is not `null`, then you never execute the query to filter by the dates because you already return a view and exit the method.

Comment: `if (search != null){ Trips = Trips.Where(...);} if (startdate != null){ Trips = Trips.Where(...);} if (enddate != null) { Trips = Trips.Where(...);} return View(Trips);`

Comment: I am not able to search by date range as it does not filter out the result..

Comment: It will work fine, but only if `search` is `null` - see the 2nd comment for the correct usage.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this but it does not work.. thank you for your help ..                 if (search != null)  {
     return View(Trips.Where(x => x.TripName.Contains(search) || x.Country.Contains(search)  || search == null).ToList()); }

                if (startdate != null ) {
                    return View(Trips.Where(x => enddate < x.endDate && startdate > x.startDate).ToList()); }

                if (enddate != null) {
                   return View(Trips.Where(x => enddate < x.endDate && startdate > x.startDate).ToList());    }
                return View(Trips);

Comment: Read the code in my comment - your do not return anything in the `if` blocks - your modify the result and return it at the end! And its `if (startdate != null ) { Trips = Trips.Where(x => startdate > x.startDate)` (and ditto for `enddate`)

Comment: I encountered this problem when i used the above code "  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<FYP2.Models.Trip>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<FYP2.Models.Trip>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" .

Comment: That is simply not possible if you used the code I gave you. You have obviously add `.ToList()` somewhere in your queries (do you see that any where in the code I gave you?)

Comment: Sorry my bad, thank you. But I am still unable to filter out the date range correctly .. I am wondering if the operators that I am using are correct ?

Comment: Give me 30 min and I'll add a complete answer with an explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` blocks in your controller code are returning a view if the result evaluates to `true`, so if `search` is not `null`, then your immediately exit the method and never get to filter the results based on the `startdate` and /or `enddate` values.

You need to create a `IQueryable<Trips>` and in each `if` block, modify the query using your `.Where()` clauses, and then at the end, return a view based on the filtered results.

Note that I'm assuming that a user can enter a `startdate` without an `enddate` and vice versa

```
public ActionResult Index(string search, DateTime? startdate, DateTime? enddate)
{
    ViewBag.Datetime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    ViewBag.startdate = startdate;
    ViewBag.enddate = enddate;

    IQueryable<Trips> trips = db.Trips;

    if (search != null)
    {
        trips = trips.Where(x => x.TripName.Contains(search) || x.Country.Contains(search);
    }
    if (startdate.HasValue)
    {
        trips = trips.Where(x => x.startDate > startdate.Value);
    }
    if (enddate.HasValue)
    {
        trips = trips.Where(x => x.enddate < enddate.Value);
    }
    // At this point the query has generated a SQL statement based on the conditions above,
    // but it will not be executed until the until the next line - i.e. when calling .ToList()
    return View(trips.ToList());
}
```

Note, its not clear if you really want `x => x.startDate > startdate.Value` or `x => x.startDate >= startdate.Value`, and depending on if your storing dates with the time component as well, you may want to use `x => x.startDate > startdate.Value.Date` (ditto for `enddate`)

As a side note, you should be using a view model rather that `ViewBag` to pass values to the view. In addition your use of `if (Session["StaffName"] != null)` suggests a problem with your design.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, but I am still unable to retrieve the date range details correctly as I want to search for both Start & End Dates and retrieve result that fall between both start and end dates.

Comment: Then either you did not use my code (which is likely considering you were unable to follow simple instructions in the comments) or your data is wrong!

Comment: How would I know. I don't know what values you entered in the form, or what the values in your database are.

Comment: okay i get it now ! Sorry for the trouble and thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this modified code...

```
public ActionResult Index(string search, DateTime? startdate, DateTime? enddate)
{
    if (Session["StaffName"] != null)
    {
        //original
        DateTime str = DateTime.UtcNow;
        ViewBag.Datetime = str;
        ViewBag.startdate = startdate;
        ViewBag.enddate = enddate;
        var Trips = from x in db.Trips
                select x;
        if (search != null)
        {
            if (startdate != null && enddate != null)
            {
                return View(Trips.Where(x =>  x.TripName.Contains(search) || x.Country.Contains(search)  || search == null && (startdate > x.startDate && x.endDate < enddate)).ToList());
            }
            else
            {
                return View(Trips.Where(x => x.TripName.Contains(search) || x.Country.Contains(search)  || search == null).ToList());
            }
        }
        if (startdate != null && enddate != null)
        {
            return View(Trips.Where(x => startdate > x.startDate && x.endDate < enddate)).ToList());
        }
        return View(Trips.ToList());
    }
}
```